# Select items from a combobox containing a specific word in vb6

Tags: combobox, vb6

My problem is that I have the following combobox in my VB6 application:

```
For Each sectionNodeTCbte In sectionsTCbte
            idTC = sectionNodeTCbte.selectSingleNode("Id").Text
            cmbTipoCbte.AddItem (sectionNodeTCbte.selectSingleNode("Desc").Text)
            cmbTipoCbte.ItemData(cmbTipoCbte.NewIndex) = idTC
Next
```

This combobox, brings me:

- Document 1
- Document 2
- StyleSheet 1
- StyleSheet 2
- Document 3

I need to show only those with the word "Document". I should use an if? Or how i could solve, any ideas?

Thank you for readme and sorry for my English!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `If` using an additional variable:

```
Dim description As String

For Each sectionNodeTCbte In sectionsTCbte
    description = sectionNodeTCbte.selectSingleNode("Desc").Text
    If InStr(description, "Document") > 0 Then
        idTC = sectionNodeTCbte.selectSingleNode("Id").Text
        cmbTipoCbte.AddItem description
        cmbTipoCbte.ItemData(cmbTipoCbte.NewIndex) = idTC
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you @trincot!!! I can solve it! But instead of InStr (idTC, "Document") I created a variable with the description of the item and then used in place of idTC. Thank you very much!! ;-)

Comment: Ah, right, I updated the answer with that. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions, if they matter in your case

1. If it's possible to have "document 1" in your list, as opposed to "Document 1", you should use vbTextCompare to ignore the case.
2. If you just want items that start with "Document" you can check that InStr() = 1. Using InStr() > 0 would be true for "This Document", which you may not want.

If InStr(Description, "Document", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then